# Unable to UnInstall ChromeDriver 2.45

Tags: macos, google-chrome, npm, selenium-chromedriver, homebrew

I am trying to uninstall ChromeDriver 2.45 and use version 2.36 for a python package that requires 2.36.

I have run every command uninstall command I can think of shown (pip, pip3, brew, npm) in the screenshot. I have even run all the same commands in the python virtual environment.

I cannot get 2.45 to leave the system.

How do I uninstall 2.45??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the binary from Google, the install is a simple copy of the binary into (usually) `/usr/local/bin`.
To uninstall, remove the binary :

```
$ whereis chromedriver
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver

$ rm /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```